# Export Critical, Warning and Errors events from Windows Logs

Tags: powershell, logging, event-viewer

I'm using most of the script from here.https://kb.webspy.com/s/article/windows-event-logs-and-powershell

However, I was wondering if there is a way only export Critical, Warning and Errors events. I know those events levels are 1-3

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName = "System"; Level=1,2,3; StartTime=((Get-Date).AddDays(-7))} -ComputerName "server1" #| Out-GridView
```

I was just wondering where to add the level to this script.

```
# Logs to extract from server
$logArray = @("System","Security","Application")

# Grabs the server name to append to the log file extraction
$servername = $env:computername

# Provide the path with ending "\" to store the log file extraction.
$destinationpath = "C:\WindowsEventLogs\"

# Checks the last character of the destination path.  If it does not end in '\' it adds one.
# '.+?\\$' +? means any character \\ is looking for the backslash $ is the end of the line charater
if ($destinationpath -notmatch '.+?\\$')
{
    $destinationpath += '\'
}

# If the destination path does not exist it will create it
if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationpath))
{
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $destinationpath
}

# Get the current date in YearMonthDay format
$logdate = Get-Date -format yyyyMMddHHmm

# Start Process Timer
$StopWatch = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::startNew()

# Start Code
Clear-Host

Foreach($log in $logArray)
{
    # If using Clear and backup
    $destination = $destinationpath + $servername + "-" + $log + "-" + $logdate + ".evtx"

    Write-Host "Extracting the $log file now."

    # Extract each log file listed in $logArray from the local server.
    wevtutil epl $log $destination

}

# End Code

# Stop Timer
$StopWatch.Stop()
$TotalTime = $StopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
$TotalTime = [math]::Round($totalTime, 2)
write-host "The Script took $TotalTime seconds to execute."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the code is [using `wevtutil` to  retrieve information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wevtutil) about event logs.

```
wevtutil epl $log $destination
```

From the documentation `wevtutil` also accept [different options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wevtutil#options) and one of which is `/q:<Query>`.

> Defines the XPath query to filter the events that are read or
> exported. If this option is not specified, all events will be returned
> or exported. This option is not available when /sq is true.

So you could create a [Xpath query to apply filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/consuming-events) based on event levels

```
wevtutil epl $log $destination /q:"*[System[(Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3)]]"
```